# how to exploit parallelism in a numpy matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

the following code generates a kind of 'skyline' profile where the initial values are 0's and the profile is made with 1's. I implemented using a for loop and I wonder if there is a more efficient way to obtain the same result.

```
#https://app.codility.com/programmers/task/max_square_on_matrix/
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
A = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=int)
X = np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size = 5)

print('A ')
print(A)
print('----------------------')
print('X ')
print(X)
#
for j in range(len(A)):
        A[5-X[j]:5,j] = 1
print('----------------------')
print('A modified ')
print(A)
```

Comment: If you were simply setting one value `A[5-X, np.arange(5)] =1`.  But with slice to the end, that approach doesn't work.   We need to generate a mask array with something like `X[:,None]<np.arange(5)`.  But details need to worked out in an answer.

Comment: Regarding the input size, parallelism will not help. The input should be quite big for parallelism to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use matrix `A` for some computation which result in numbers other than 1 or 0, you can simply treat 1 and 0 like True and False:

```
N = 5
X = np.random.randint(low=1, high=N, size = (N,1) )
A = (X >= range(N,0,-1)).T
```

**EDIT:**

Oooop, I responded too quickly. Turns out my method is not "more efficient" than the for loop for N=5.

Also, the following works slightly better than my original answer, especially for large N:

```
a = np.array(range(N,0,-1),ndmin=2).T
X = np.random.randint(low=1, high=N, size=N)
A = X>=a
```

On my computer, this is a tiny bit slower than the for loop when N=5. However, when N=100, it is 2 times faster than doing the for loop.

Comment: Also, if you really need the `A.dtype == int` instead of `bool`, then do `A = np.empty((N,N), dtype=int)` and  `A[:] = X>=a`.